# How would I combine multiple conditions using AND and OR operators in JavaScript ternary statements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

I am implementing a simple react page with a counter counting down from 10 to 00.

I know that I can just use an if statement to do my code, but I was wondering, for efficiency, whether or not I can use multiple conditions in the same line for a ternary statement.

I tried searching this up, but no one on StackOverflow has asked this question. I'm not sure if it's because it is so mindnumpingly dumb or if it's just not good practice.

This is the code that I have thus far.

```
  const stopTimer = false;

  const stopBtnHandler = () => {
    stopTimer = true;
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
      const timer = setInterval(() => {
        //this is the ternary statement...since it only checks the true case, it has this weird syntax with the &&
         count > 0 && setCount((data) => data - 1);
      }, 1000);

      return () => clearInterval(timer);
  },[count])

  return (
    <>
      <Half className='left-side'>
        <Wrap>
          <p>{count.toString().padStart(2, '0')}</p>
          <StyledButton onClick={plusBtnHandler}>+</StyledButton>
          {/* <button onClick={minusBtnHandler}>-</button> */}
          <StyledButton onClick={resetBtnHandler}>Reset</StyledButton>
          <StyledButton onClick={stopBtnHandler}></StyledButton>
        </Wrap>
      </Half>
      <Half className='right-side'>
          <h1>Hello</h1>
      </Half>
    </>
  )
```

this is what I was trying to implement

```
if (count > 0 AND stopTimer === true) { 
    setCount( (data) => data - 1); 
}
```

Comment: What are the multiple conditions you are trying to use?

Comment: You can use some approaches like: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns.  For example: break your conditions into some smaller conditions/functions

Comment: I don't see any if statements and I don't see any ternary statements, so I'm completely lost.

Comment: @Unmitigated I am trying to implement this in a ternary operator

`
if (count > 0 and stopTimer == True){
    setCount(  (data) => data - 1);
}
`

I should have shown some more of the code. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `&& !stopTimer`?

Comment: @Unmitigated Yeah, my bad again. Sorry about this. I am a beginner in computer science.

Comment: You can indeed use `count > 0 && !stopTimer && setCount(data => data - 1)` then. But an if statement should be preferred.